# Reshaping data frame with many NAs

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame in R with four variables:

| id | var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NA | 0.4 | NA |
| 1 | 0.8 | NA | NA |
| 2 | 0.7 | NA | NA |
| 2 | NA | 0.5 | NA |
| 2 | NA | NA | 0.1 |
| 3 | NA | 0.5 | NA |
| 3 | NA | NA | 0.2 |

There are repeated entries per id and each observation only contains one data value besides the id. I would like to obtain one observation per id with all of the data values "collected".
The output should look like this:

| id | var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.8 | 0.4 | NA |
| 2 | 0.7 | 0.5 | 0.1 |
| 3 | NA | 0.5 | 0.2 |

I have played around with pivot_wider, data.table, gather, but am not getting anywhere. It seems to me that this should be very simple. Like some sort of collapse. Grateful for any pointers.

Answer (score 2):

Or using `summarise` per group:

```r
library(dplyr)

df |>
  group_by(id) |>
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ first(na.omit(.))))
```

Output:

```r
# A tibble: 3 × 4
     id  var1  var2  var3
  <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   0.8   0.4  NA  
2     2   0.7   0.5   0.1
3     3  NA     0.5   0.2
```

Thanks to @Darren Tsai for the data.

Comment: I seem to only be getting the complete cases here. So only those observations that have no NAs are retained; i.e. id=2

Comment: Hi @lfgroene. Strange. Could you provide some sample data? Using Darren Tsai's data, I cannot reproduce the problem you have. The output is consistently like the one in my post.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tidyr::fill` by groups and then subset unique rows.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  fill(var1:var3, .direction = "downup") %>%
  distinct() %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 3 × 4
#      id  var1  var2  var3
#   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     1   0.8   0.4  NA  
# 2     2   0.7   0.5   0.1
# 3     3  NA     0.5   0.2
```

---

###### Data

```r
df <- read.table(text = "
id  var1    var2    var3
1   NA  0.4 NA
1   0.8 NA  NA
2   0.7 NA  NA
2   NA  0.5 NA
2   NA  NA  0.1
3   NA  0.5 NA
3   NA  NA  0.2", header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first `pivot_longer`, then remove `NA`, and finally `pivot_wider`back again:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = name, values_from = value)
# A tibble: 3 × 4
     id  var2  var1  var3
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   0.4   0.8  NA  
2     2   0.5   0.7   0.1
3     3   0.5  NA     0.2
```